# Search for a text in column B and past other text to column L if true

Tags: excel, vba

I need to search in column B:B for a specific text, then if true paste other text to column L:L, exemple:

[image]

```
Sub teste()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    last = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = last To 1 Step -1    
        If (Cells(i, "B").Value) = "string_1" Then    
            Range("L2").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "some_text_1"

            'LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            'Range("L2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L" & LastRow)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I can only paste the first text if true or fill the column L:L with the same text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like that?

- If column B is `string_1` then copy column C to column L

---

```
For i = last To 1 Step -1    
    If (Cells(i, "B").Value) = "string_1" Then    

        'copy value from C to L
        Cells(i, "L").Value = Cells(i, "C").Value

    End If
Next i
```

You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Thanks for the help! But the code didn't pass anything, in fact he image is an example, search on A and if true paste a text ( .Value = "some text" ) to C. I'm working with B to L columns.

Comment: Well this is an example how it works in general. You still need to put in some effort and adjust the column names to whatever you need. This code checks if column B is `string_1` then copy column C to column L. If you need other columns change them to your needs.

Comment: With your help, I have created a solution. Sorry, I didn't get it at first look.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub teste()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

s1 = "first_text"
s2 = "second_text"
s3 = "third_text"

last = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = last To 1 Step -1

If (Cells(i, "B").Value) = "string_1" Then
    Cells(i, "L").Value = s1
ElseIf (Cells(i, "B").Value) = "String_2" Then
    Cells(i, "L").Value = s2
ElseIf (Cells(i, "B").Value) = "string_3" Then
    Cells(i, "L").Value = s3
End If

Next i

End Sub
```